# How do I share my Google Maker addresses as places on my website?

Tags: google-maps

I've added 26 addresses how do I show this on my website with places?

I'm using Google Makers.

Comment: Which website are you using? You may get latitude and longitude as arrays to set the Markers

Comment: http://www.google.com/mapmaker